# Returning an Object without having to cast afterwards

Tags: java

I have a method that works with different classes implementing the same common interface. The interface is generic and the classes implementing it may contain objects of any kind as instance variables. All of the classes that get used by my method contain different types of objects. I need my method to return the object the given class contains. Since the contained object can be of any type I'm forced to cast the return value to "Object" and then downcast it back when I'm using the value. Is there any better workaround for this?

```
public class Foo {

    // this method is the problem since it can't keep the type getData returns
    public static Object method(I i) {
        return i.getData();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        I a = new A();
        I b = new B();
        Integer s1 = (Integer)method(a);  // this should work without the cast
        Integer s2 = method(b);  // this shouldn't work of course
    }


    public static interface I<T> {

        public T getData();

    }

    public static class A implements I<Integer> {

        public Integer getData() {
            return 1;
        }

    }

    public static class B implements I<String> {

        public String getData() {
            return "data";
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Not sure why  you would need a static method  like that. I have however posted a solution.   You might  consider creating an Abstract class that implements I and defining methods there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public static  <T> T method(I<T> i) {
    return i.getData();
}
```

Comment: This works when you avoid upcasting "a" and "b" to "I", thanks. The actual code is a bit more complicated, I'm using something like A and B as "custom instance variables" that have their own parse methods and stuff. Then I can get their values by calling them by name from a list containing all the "instance variables" that belong to a parent class